# Relations between control characters, signals and terminal

Tags: terminal, signals, special-characters

What are the relations between control characters and signals? Or are they unrelated?

Are control characters received by a terminal?

After a terminal receives a control character, is the terminal sending out a signal to a process one of the possible action of the terminal to the received control character?

For example,

in Linux, in a terminal, Ctrl+C will terminate a running foreground process. In ASCII, Ctrl+C is [a control character which means "     End of Text"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

In ASCII, Ctrl+D is a control character which means end of transmission. Does the control character make the terminal send out some signal to some process?

Comment: A control+c may or may not cause a running foreground process to terminate, depending on signal masking. The control+c will cause a SIGINT to be sent to all processes in the foreground process group (often including the shell, which means SIGINT handling in modern shells can be hilariously complicated).

Answer (score 10):

The *terminal driver* (part of the operating system) establishes the relationship between [special characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09) and signals.  Your *terminal settings*, e.g., using [`stty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html), are what it uses to decide what (if anything) to do with characters that you type.  You can reassign those special characters as needed with a few caveats:

- only one special character per function
- only single-byte characters are used

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> are *conventional*: while a few applications may hardcode these values, the terminal driver does not require that.

The terminal driver is software, not part of your *terminal*.  For some keyboards you may find different assignments of special characters more convenient than others (and for different operating systems, a few choices of the default values for the special characters may differ).

Further reading:

- [11.1.9 Special Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09) (POSIX *General Terminal Interface)
- [11. General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html)
- [stty - set the options for a terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html)

Comment: Not necessarily any driver at all beyond what's used for an RS232 port when talking of control *characters*. Terminals are very easily bit banged. And not all terminals are emulated or have ncurses definitions in terminfo.

Answer (score 4):

Control characters and signals are sort of related. You can see what the match between signals and characters are with `stty -a` command in a terminal.  A RHEL server I can access says:

```
-bash-3.2$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 135; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -cdtrdsr
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Some of that is related to the TTY and what it does to input, other stuff to signals. The parts for signals:

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; susp = ^Z;
```

That means SIGINT is control-C, SIGQUIT is control-backslash and SIGSTOP is control-Z. You can reassign any or all of those, if you like. See `man stty`.

The other control characters like `erase` or `werase` are intercepted and used by the terminal driver itself. Like when you backspace, the terminal driver erases a character from the screen and from the input stream. The "mode" of the terminal driver (raw or cooked, possibly partially cooked) makes a difference as well. Text editors like `vim` and `emacs` make heavy use of control characters, and they don't get a SIGINT or SIGQUIT or whatever when you type those control characters. A program can set the TTY to "raw mode" and just read the bytes without interpretation by the terminal driver.

Comment: i will never not be amused by the fact there's still a measurement of speed in `baud`

Comment: `baud` is still used when controlling serial ports. Serial ports can have all sorts of stuff attached.

Comment: @tac believe it or not, [some of us still have serial terminals](http://i.imgur.com/UIQ33qG.jpg) and actually need this. Pictured: a setup program that failed in xterm and emulated tty's and required a serial port terminal (the bug's been fixed, but they are valuable for debugging). Model IBM 3161